# No puedo agregar el texto a mi archivo desde mi interfaz grafica

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

tengo una consulta.
Estoy programando una interfaz grafica en tkinter, quiero decir que este es un proyecto pero no estoy para nada familiarizado con orientación a objetos, sin embargo se me ocurrio hacer lo siguiente.

Tengo una pagina de inicio con boton de registro o iniciar sesion, ando programando la de registro, ya logre colocar los cuadros para que el usuario escriba y demas. Ahora bien, cuando trato de escribir en mi archivo csv ya existente lo que el usuario ha agregado, no puedo ver absolutamente nada, intente con el metodo write, y si crea el archivo pero no escribe nada, a continuacion mi codigo

```
#esto forma parte de otra funcion declarada antes
nombre = tk.StringVar()
username = tk.StringVar()
contrasenia = tk.StringVar()
email = tk.StringVar()

nombre_entrada = tk.Entry(pagina_registro,textvariable=nombre,width=50)
nombre_entrada.place(x=5,y=135)
usuario_entrada = tk.Entry(pagina_registro,textvariable=username,width=50)
usuario_entrada.place(x=5,y=210)
contrasenia_entrada = tk.Entry(pagina_registro,textvariable=contrasenia,width=50, show='*')
contrasenia_entrada.place(x=5,y=285)
email_entrada = tk.Entry(pagina_registro,textvariable=email,width=50)
email_entrada.place(x=5,y=360)

def registrar():#esta es una funcion declarada dentro de otra funcion
    data_nombre = nombre.get()
    data_user = username.get()
    data_contrasenia = str(contrasenia.get())
    data_email = str(email.get())  
    
    data_base = open('datos.txt','w')
    data_base.write('\n')
    data_base.write(data_nombre)
    data_base.write(',')
    data_base.write(data_user)
    data_base.write(',')
    data_base.write(data_contrasenia)
    data_base.write(',')
    data_base.write(data_email)
    data_base.close()

register = tk.Button(pagina_registro, text='registrar',command=registrar)
register.pack()
```

me podrian ayudar? no se que esta pasando, las comas si me las agrega, los campos de entrada no

Comment: no estoy seguro que para escribir en un *.csv* sea de la misma forma que en un *.txt*

Comment: lo intente tambien como txt y no paso nada :(

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en tkinter pero dado que tu problema es al escribir en un archivo tratare de ayudarte, primero verifica que en realidad estés obteniendo los datos, si ese no es el error, pasamos a la siguiente solución. Vamos a simplificar tu código.

```py
def registrar():
    ....
    with open('datos.txt','w') as data_base:
        content = f "\n {data_nombre},{data_user},{data_contrasenia},{data_email}"
        data_base.write(content)
```

De esa forma simplificamos las líneas de código, una ventaja de utilizar `with` es que no tenemos que indicarle que cierre el archivo ya que el lo hace automáticamente al terminar su bloque. Si tu problema sigue, házmelo saber :)

Comment: Hola, logre resolver el problema, pero como tu bien dices se puede hacer un codigo mas simplificado y eficiente, asi que aplique lo que tu me dices con los cambios que le tuve que hacer y se ve hasta mejor el codigo, gracias!

Comment: Que bueno, si deseas puedes compartir la forma en que lo resolviste, así otras personas con el mismo problema podrán aprender